# Calling C# Method from C++ via Delegates Results in Reversed Parameters

Tags: c#, c++, interop, unmanaged

I am trying to have a C++ function call a method on a form in C# in order to update the GUI. For some reason, the function call from C++ sends the parameters in reversed order.

So the `UpdateDROCallback()` function gets 3.0 for the first parameter, 2.0 for the second, and 1.0 for the last when it was called with function(1.0, 2.0, 3.0).

What am I missing here?

[C#]

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        delegate void DROUpdateDelegate(double x, double y, double z);
        DROUpdateDelegate m_DROUpdateDelegate;
        static DROUpdateDelegate s_DROUpdateDelegate;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_DROUpdateDelegate = new DROUpdateDelegate(UpdateDROCallback);
            s_DROUpdateDelegate = new DROUpdateDelegate(UpdateDRO);
        }

        private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int address = m_DROUpdateDelegate.Method.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().ToInt32();
            TestDll.RegisterScaleUpdateCallback(address);
        }

        private static void UpdateDROCallback(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            s_DROUpdateDelegate(x, y, z);
        }

        private void UpdateDRO(double x, double y, double z)
        {
            BeginInvoke(
                new Action(
                    () =>
                    {
                        lblDROX.Text = x.ToString("0.0000");
                        lblDROY.Text = y.ToString("0.0000");
                        lblDROZ.Text = z.ToString("0.0000");
                    }));
        }
    }
```

TestDll.cs:

```
public static class TestDll
{
    (...)
    [DllImport("test.dll", EntryPoint = "RegisterScaleUpdateCallback")]
    public static extern void RegisterScaleUpdateCallback(int address);
    (...)
}
```

[C++]

StrobeTest.h:

```
#pragma once
class StrobeTest
{
    typedef void (__stdcall *DROUpdate)(double x, double y, double z);

private:
    static DROUpdate s_CallbackFunction;
public:
    StrobeTest(void);
    ~StrobeTest(void);

    static void InitializeStrobe(void);
    static void MoveXAtSpeed(double velocity);
    static void CALLBACK RegisterScaleUpdateCallback(DROUpdate function);
};
```

StrobeTest.cpp

```
(...)
void StrobeTest::RegisterScaleUpdateCallback(DROUpdate function)
{
    StrobeTest::s_CallbackFunction = function;
    StrobeTest::s_CallbackFunction(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
}
(...)
```

Comment: You cannot use MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().  Change the declaration of RegisterScaleUpdateCallback() to take a delegate instead of an int.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks, that is it! Do you happen to know why this is the case? I thought a function address is a function address.

Comment: You have to go through a stub that switches into managed code execution, a garbage collector detail.  And the calling convention for managed functions is different, the reason the arguments looked wrong.  The underlying core method is Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate().

Answer (score 1):

Show the code of `TestDll`, especially the declaration of `TestDll.RegisterScaleUpdateCallback` in it. There will be the cause. Make sure that the calling conventions match.